# Bug in automatic connection to Wi-Fi, multiple identical points of connection are creating

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

My code for automatic connection to Wi-Fi:

```
  int networkId = wifi.getConnectionInfo().getNetworkId();
 wifi.removeNetwork(networkId);
 int netId = wifi.addNetwork(conf);
 wifi.enableNetwork(netId, true);
 wifi.saveConfiguration();
 wifi.reconnect();
```

Everything is connecting correctly, but in the settings many identical Wi-Fi points appears. It can be fixed only by turning on/off the Wi-Fi.
I understand that I can solve this by disabling / enabling wifi. But is there any better solution?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Hooray! I found a solution! I must delete all entries for this point:

```
List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
                    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
                        wifi.removeNetwork(i.networkId);
                        wifi.saveConfiguration();
                    }
                    int netId = wifi.addNetwork(conf);
                    wifi.enableNetwork(netId, true);
                    wifi.reconnect();
```